# FileSystem FilePutobject Issues

Tags: vb.net

I have written the following code using "**FilePutObject**" in VB.NET in order to write a file in VB.NET.

```
Dim str = "This is a Test"
FileSystem.FileOpen(1, "c:\temp\file1.txt", OpenMode.Binary)
FileSystem.FilePutObject(1, str, 2)
FileSystem.FileClose(1)
```

When I check the file, I found few junk character has been added before the text.

Then I used  "**FilePut**" in order to write the file:

```
Dim str = "This is a Test"
FileSystem.FileOpen(1, "c:\temp\file1.txt", OpenMode.Binary)
FileSystem.FilePut(1, str, 2)
FileSystem.FileClose(1)
```

The text in the file is written perfectly while using  **FilePut**. What could be the reason behind this? Also, I found ****FilePut*** is obsolete and **FilePutObject** should be used instead*. How I can write correctly using **FilePutObject** ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but have you considered using the more modern System.IO.WriteAllText method?

Comment: FilePutObject is a carry-over from older vb code. You should only use it when porting old code to .net. Do not use it for new development.

Answer (score 4):

This is normal behaviour.  You are outputting objects to a binary file - this is not generating a pure text file and `FilePutObject` is not the right tool to use if you want to generate a text file (or for new development at all, really).

In this case the "junk" characters belong to the string descriptor in the object file.  These first four bytes in your case can be best understood by looking at the raw values written to the file :

[image: hex edit view]

The first two bytes describe the variable type (See : [VarType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kfz157h%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)) - `00 08` here for `vbString`.  The next two give the string length, `00 0e`, or 14, because there are 14 characters in the string.

They are in place so that when reading out multiple objects from the file the read function can identify the type and size of each object such that it knows how much to read and where to stop before reaching the next object.

If you want to write a text file, consider using a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx).

For example :

```
Dim str as String = "This is a Test"
Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("c:\temp\file1.txt")
        sw.WriteLine(str)
End Using
```

Comment: What is the solution? As it as been suggested to use FilePutObject as FilePut is invalid.

Comment: @user1672097 - consider using a StreamWriter (linked in answer to MSDN with examples).

Comment: I can understand 08 for Vartype and 0e for 14.Then why two more extra 00?

Comment: @user1672097 - the extra zeroes aren't extra, they're just not needed for smaller numbers.  You can have strings longer than 255 characters, for example, so you would need the extra byte to fit its length.  The vartype, also can be larger than 255 (ie: vbArray = 8192 = x2000) so the space is needed for the format to accomodate all objects of all sizes.

Comment: So is FilePut is ok for writing ? I beleive the root cause is I am attempting to write a txt file in binary mode?

Comment: @user1672097 - it doesn't include the descriptors (because it's not writing objects or multiple objects) but as I (and others) have said, you're best to not use either `FilePut` or `FilePutObject` - they are old methods that have much better modern counterparts.  I would consider using a StreamWriter (as I have suggested and linked to).

Comment: I beleive the root cause is I am attempting to write a txt file in binary mode?

Comment: @user1672097 yes, you are writing in binary mode and are therefore getting extra information about the written object.  Please see here for information about using a StreamWriter instead : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx  (Scroll to the bottom to find example code).  I have also added an example in my answer.